# Is it pythonic for a function to return chained values / set variables on itself?

Tags: python

Is it pythonic to return multiple values from a function in this way?

```
def f():
    f.x = 1
    f.y = 2
    return f

r = f()
print r.x,r.y
1 2
```

Comment: Is it good practice. Aparently not

Comment: Not meaning to return the function but only the multiple return values and access them in the r.x and r.y way

Comment: It might be better to describe what you are trying to do, and ask how to do it.

Comment: @user2568730 But you *are* returning the function from itself.

Comment: @djechlin I wasn't calling anything out.......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, "Pythonic" is a term in the literature to mean the "right" way of doing things. So the user really doesn't have to do any further explaining, in that case.

Comment: I usually interpret "Pythonic" to mean "using methods generally recommended by the Python programming community".  Given that any group of N persons generally has *at least* N+1 'recommendations', mine may be a distinction without merit.

Comment: I think by "pythonic" they mean "idiomatic". You can program in Python as in other GP language (for example, restricting yourself to RPython level of language features) or in million other ways, as opposed to using the specific language features as they were intended, and writing code in the style proposed by relevant PEPs etc. For example I'm sure that what he wants here is to retrn a tuple i.e. `x,y=f()`or a namedtuple, whereas returning a class (with `x` and `y` properties) would probably be sanest, albeit slightly less idiomatic/pythonic way to do it, depending on context.

Comment: @djechlin: Angry much?  Every language has idiomatic and non-idiomatic ways of doing things.  "Pythonic" just means "in the generally accepted Python idiom."  If you don't like it, use Perl, where "there's more than one way to do it" is accepted and encouraged.  Just don't complain when you have to maintain someone else's code where they used a bunch of tricks you aren't familiar with...

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller There's actually more than one way to do most things in python which are equally as good as each other.

Comment: atta boy. ask it away

Comment: "Primarily opinion based"

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed as "primarily opinion based" as the answers show a surprising level of unanimity on both the problem and the cure.

Comment: You should accept an answer (click the green check mark by the votes); I think Marcin's is the best.

Answer (score 39):

You're not "returning chained values", you're creating a function which returns itself, after setting variables on itself.

The problem with this is that if you reinvoke the function (assuming it isn't just a constant function as shown in your example) is that every single appearance of the function (and understand that `r` is the same as `f` in your code) will have those values change. You'll have this problem whether or not your programme uses multiple threads.

The normal way to return multiple values is simply to return a tuple, which can be the source of a destructuring (sequence) assignment. Alternatively, if you want to manage a bunch of variables together, you would use an object. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 33):

No. You are changing a global object that is not thread safe.

More common is

```
return 1, 2
```

or, if you want to have names,

```
return {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Comment: Or an object, if there's justification for it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. I was thinking on templates for the second one

Comment: Thread safety isn't even the main problem. It will give unexpected results in a single thread.

Answer (score 20):

It's not pythonic, it is not even *reasonable* for any language that potentially supports such a  construct.

What you do is that you use the function's global state as a carrier of your output values. To return a value from a function you should use, well, a *return value*, not the called function. In your example you cannot be really sure what is your return value:

```
>> def f(x):
...   f.x=x
...   return f
...
>>> z=f(1)
>>> z.x
1
>>> f(2)    # <--- alters global state of the function
<function f at 0x10045c5f0>
>>> z.x
2           # <--- errr, five lines ago z.x was 1, no?
```

You can use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a custom [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) (although using `type()` might be perceived as too low level):

```
>>> def dict_as_tuple(**kwargs):
...     return type('CustomType', (object,), kwargs)()
...
>>> z = dict_as_tuple(x=1, y=2)
>>> z.x
1
>>> z.y
2
```

Regarding the [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), a common way is to return `self` (if you want to change state of the object) or new object of the same type (objects are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which is *good*)

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...      self.x = x
...   def add(self, y):
...     return C(self.x + y)
...   def mul(self, y):
...     return C(self.x * y)
...
>>> C(0).add(1).mul(10).x
10
```

Answer (score 18):

All of the advice given so far is good, but doesn't show much code, here they are, one by one.

The most common answer was 'return a tuple', which would look like this

```
def f():
    return 1, 2

x, y = f()
```

A related answer was 'return a `namedtuple`':

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

def f():
    return Point(1, 2)

r = f()
print r.x, r.y
```

another idea was to use 'objects'.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.x, self.y = x, y

r = Foo(1, 2)
print r.x, r.y
```

You mention 'chaining' in your question; as though you want repeated calls to `f()` to give different results.  That's doable, too, with generators.

```
def f_gen():
    for x in range(1, 10)
        yield x, x + 1

f = f_gen()
print f()
print f()
```

Comment: I'd give more than +1 if I could.  Very clean code, making all the options clear!

Answer (score 7):

This is what's wrong:

```
>>> def f(a):
...   f.x = a
...   return f
...
>>> r = f(1)
>>> print r.x
1
>>> p = f(2)
>>> print p.x
2
>>> print r.x
2
```

It isn't expected that r is also changed! So not good practice to do it this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can return a tuple:

```
def f():
    return 1,2

x,y = f()
print x,y
...
(1,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

See other comments to your question if it's pythonic...
As an easy solution you could use a class instead..

```
class cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 1, 2
r = cls()
print(r.x, r.y) # 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you need to retain some state information, is to use a class and overload the **__*call*__** method.

```
class f:
    def __call__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
        return self.x, self.y

r = f()
print(r())
```

That will print:

```
(1, 2)
```